# Can we do file handing in jQuery like C#?

Tags: c#, jquery

My question is that can I do the file handing in jQuery like in C#. Suppose I want to get all directories from the particulate path we can write the code like given below.

```
string foldersPath = @"C:\Filesystem\Staging\Incoming";

if (Directory.Exists(foldersPath))
{
    string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(foldersPath, "*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
}
```

Now I want to write down this code in jQuery.

Is it possible? If yes please provide me some demo code.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot directly access the file system via JavaScript or jQuery, but you can use a jQuery `.ajax()` call to call a server-side resource, such as an .aspx page, .ashx (HTTP handler), ASP.NET AJAX Page Method, .asmx web service, WCF web service; which could return to you a `string[]` of file information via JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You **can't do this in client side scripting** using `Javascript` or `jQuery`, which is **insecure**.  This has to be done only in server side(secure).

**Update:**

If you're interested in **`HTML5`** then take a look at this [**Reading files in JavaScript using the File APIs**](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)